# best practice for types and locations of bin folders

Tags: linux, filesystems

What is a stable minimum set of Linux binary folders? Please refer to knowledge of operationally stable systems and consider [FHS standards](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html).

I am starting with the following information:

1. UseCases:

- to perform work

  - user personal work, full access for that user
  - All users, read-only for the systems users
- to make-use-of system devices and hardware components

  - read-only to all system users
- to administer the system

  - only available to system administrators

2. [FHS standards](https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.html) (simplified):

   - `/opt`, manually installed third-party. binaries, config and libraries
   - `/usr`, user programs. executable files, libraries, config and doco
   - `/bin`, system shell commands
   - `/sbin` binaries for system administration
   - `/home/[username]`, users personal programs and libraries
3. `$PATH` variable of a live system ([Alpine Linux r3.17](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.17), BusyBox):

   - `/usr/local/bin`, read-only all system users
   - `/usr/bin`, read-only all system users
   - `/bin`, read-only all system users
   - `/home/[username]/.local/bin`, specific user
   - `/usr/local/sbin`, only system administrator
   - `/usr/sbin`, only system administrator
   - `/sbin`, only system administrator
4. Package management tools ([Alpine Linux r3.17](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.17), BusyBox):

   - `apk info --who-owns [FILE|DIRECTORY]`

Comment: `/bin` and `/sbin` are symlinks to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` respectively in modern linux as far as I'm aware

Comment: There is still merit to having `/bin` and `/usr/bin`: to put these on sepatate partitions with different flags (`wxallowed` / `suid`).

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge these are the minimum, usually included on the path by default $PATH.

These are needed:

- Programs a User installs for their personal use

  - `/home/[username]`
- Programs installed by administrators for all users

  - `/usr`
- Shell commands to run against system devices for all users

  - `/bin`
- Shell commands for System Administration restricted access

  - `/sbin`

Explanatory notes:

- tools such as `apk info --who-owns  [FILE|DIRECTORY]` removes the need for separate folder for manual installation packages.

  - care still needed to maintain non-conflicting file naming
  - multiple versions of the same library ... binutils gets confused [Landley R, 2006](https://busybox.net/%7Elandley/firmware/design.html), I believe these dont error as modern Linux systems read $PATH from the beginning  [@coneslayer, 2011](https://superuser.com/a/238993/918779)
- /bin and /usr/sbin were split ... because Ken Thompson and Dennis Ritchie ran out of space on the original 2.5 megabyte RK-05 disk pack [Landley R, 2006](https://busybox.net/%7Elandley/firmware/design.html)